# Is it common to reboot an unmanaged gigabit network switch after an AP/Router reboot?

Tags: switch, openwrt

I have a gigabit network switch (cheap consumer version, [LevelOne GSW-0507](http://global.level1.com/Switch/GSW-0507/p-3255.htm)). It's connected to an AP running OpenWRT. I can ping LAN clients running Linux using the hostname or the IP address. However, whenever I reboot the AP I have to power on/off the network switch to get hostname resolution even though pinging them works using the IP address. WAN and Internet connectivity all work in either case.

Is it common to power cycle the network switch or do I have to fix the configuration of the setup?

Comment: Probably related to the nic on you pc. Rebooting the switch isn't necessary (AFAIK) but by rebooting the switch you are essentially unplugging the nic on your PC and plugging it back in, this initializing renegotiation with the restarted AP

Comment: @benashby You're right. I tried disconnecting the ethernet cables and it had the same effect as rebooting the switch.  Thanks for clearing this up.